# How to remove parentheses from output?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using these lines of codes:

```
let messagebody = (messagedata! .valueForKey("message"))!
print("reveived msg \(messagebody)")
```

and getting this output

```
reveived msg (
      hi
)
```

but i need only hi in output.

Please guide me that how to remove these parentheses?

Comment: get like messagebody[0]

Comment: looks like messagebody returns array

Comment: messageData["message"]?.firstObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the value of `messagebody` returns array so you get objet using Index , for ex

```
let messagebody = (messagedata! .valueForKey("message"))!
  print(messagebody[0])
```